# Cucumber steps always reported as skipped

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara

I have a set of cucumber tests that use Capybara to access a website and perform certain tasks.  The tests run fine and at the end they output accurate information about whether or not the tests and steps failed or passed. For example,

```
1 scenario (1 failed)
3 steps (1 failed, 2 passed)
```

However, if I try to write a customer formatter or even use one of the built-in custom formatters (such as progress or pretty), it shows that all of the steps are being skipped.

Does anyone know why this could be? Again, I think that all of the steps are executing properly and cucumber is reporting back to me at the end if they failed or passed (as I would expect), but the formatters seem to always think that the steps are being skipped.

Comment: Have you been able to reduce your problem at all? For example, can you delete all but one of your tests and then remove most / all of the code from that test? Please also amend your question with information like the command you are using to run cucumber (with and without the formatter) the version of cucumber and ruby, and any global cucumber configuration that you might have set.

Comment: Are you able to post the Gherkin code you're running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a scenario outline, there's a limitation in the parser that causes them to be reported as skipped: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/issues/316

You can run Cucumber with the `--expand` flag (or `-x` for short) to output each step in the scenario outline for every row in the the example table. Then they should report as passed or failed as expected.

Comment: Thanks...The expand flag did exactly what I wanted